# Re-Writing ordinary methods with async and await

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await, c#-5.0

i am using a method structure like this in my application,

```
 public void BiginAuthenticate()
 {

    if (condtion == true)
    PerformSecondLevelAuthenitcation();

 }

 public void secondlevelAuthendiation()
 {

 }
```

I written this code in a singleton class and i will access this code through my viewmodel. What i am trying to achieve is, i need to rewrite this code with asyc and await. And i need to await my first method call ie, BiginAuthenticate() until it completes both method execution. So for achieving this what is the change i need to implement in my existing code.

Comment: There is no asynchrony here (that you've shown).  `await` doesn't *create* asynchrony, it merely helps manage it through an easier syntax.  If you want it to be functionally the same, `await` does you no good.  If you want to turn a synchronous code snippet into an asynchronous code snippet, then `await` could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understud you correctly :

```
 await BiginAuthenticate();


 public async Task BiginAuthenticate()
 {

    if (condtion)
        await PerformSecondLevelAuthenitcation();

 }

 public async Task PerformSecondLevelAuthenitcation()
 {

 }
```

Comment: OP: Additionally, you should call your method `BeginAuthenticateAsync()`

Comment: And replace `condition == true` with `condition`.